# RewriteRule does not work with special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

The following rule does not work in `.htaccess`, it gives a **404 Not Found error**.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)şota.html$ /eto.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Why?

How can I use special characters in `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Providing your `.htaccess` file is saved with the UTF-8 encoding there is nothing more you need to do. What is the actual URL you are trying to match? (What do you see in the HTTP request headers?) It's more likely the regex is wrong in some other way or you have a conflict with other directives.

Comment: @MrWhite, I use notepad to edit .htaccess, I couldn't find where to check encoding of the file, but I see a normal ş character in the file.
Actual URL is something like 'example.com/ab/abc/abc-şota.html'.
I see in HTTP request that filename has '%C5%9F' instead of 'ş', and content-type is 'charset=iso-8859-1'.
I don't think that I have a conflict with other rules.

Comment: @MrWhite, I checked without special characters, the rule worked, so it is not about conflicting rules.

Comment: Try it without the `^(.*)` prefix on the regex (it's not required anyway and is just making the regex less efficient). ie. `şota\.html$` (the literal dot should be backslash escaped, but that's not the problem here).

Comment: _"I see in HTTP request that filename has '%C5%9F' instead of 'ş', and content-type is 'charset=iso-8859-1'."_ - that is a weird combination already; the former is clearly UTF-8, but then your page _content_ is in ISO-8859-1? I mean, these two do not necessarily _have to_ match, but you'd probably be making your life a lot easier, if you handled everything in UTF-8.

Comment: _"I couldn't find where to check encoding of the file, but I see a normal ş character in the file"_ - that really doesn't prove anything - it just means, the editor is showing you the data interpreted in the correct encoding, but it doesn't say anything about what that encoding actually is. So go and find that out first of all, please. (Notepad++ for example can easily show you which encoding it used when opening the file, and can convert to other encodings as well.)

Comment: @Cbroe About HTTP request, I didn't set charset=iso-8859-1, but maybe because I use <meta charset="UTF-8"> for all pages and also <html lang="tr"> for this page.
Anyway, I downloaded Notepad++, converted .htaccess encoding from ANSI to UTF-8, and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: @seeker You should add that (about the encoding) as an "answer" (and later accept it). Btw, `<meta charset="UTF-8">` doesn't "change/convert" the encoding of the file/response, it simply instructs the user-agent what encoding to use to display the response. (But there is likely a `Content-Type` header in the response that is overriding this anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon advice, and with the help of comments, I am adding the answer;

I downloaded the .htaccess file, changed the encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 via Notepad++, and it worked!